# What is the problem? dd($data); It does not return anything

Tags: php, laravel

Displays the information correctly, but when I change the name or email and click on the edit button, the page reloads and nothing happens. What's the problem?

I put this form for the user to be able to edit his information

The name of the index.blade.php form located in the veiw / userPanel path

```
@extends('layouts.master')
 
@section('title', 'UserPanel')
 
@section('content')
 
<div class="Profile" dir="rtl">
    <div class="row container">
 
        <aside class="sidebarWrap sidebar-group col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 ">
            @include('userPanel.sidebar')
        </aside>
 
        <div id="main" class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
            <div class="personal_information">
                <p class="bold" id="blue_icon" class="">info</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row container personal_information">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                            <form class="form row" action="{{ route('userPanel.update', $user->id) }}" method="POST" id="registrationForm"
                                style="margin-bottom: 0px;padding-right: 0.75rem;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;">
                                @csrf
                                @method('PATCH')
                                <div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <label for="first_name">
                                                <p>name:</p>
                                            </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-info" name="first_name" id="first_name"
                                                value="{{ $user->name }}" placeholder=""
                                                title="enter your first name if any.">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <label for="mobile">
                                                <p>phone:</p>
                                            </label>
                                            <input dir="ltr" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-info"
                                                value="{{ $user->phone }}"
                                                placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <label for="email">
                                                <p>email:</p>
                                            </label>
                                            <input dir="ltr" type="email" class="form-info" name="email" id="email"
                                                value="{{ $user->email }}" placeholder="you@email.com"
                                                title="enter your email.">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-submit " type="submit">edit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
</div>
 
@endsection
```

I also created this controller called userInfoController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Profile;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class userInfoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('userPanel.index', compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        return view('userPanel.index', compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
        ]);
        dd($data);

        $user->update($data);

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u close div at wrong position, should like this

```
<div class="row container">

    <aside class="sidebarWrap sidebar-group col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 ">
        @include('userPanel.sidebar')
    </aside>

    <div id="main" class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
        <div class="personal_information">
            <p class="bold" id="blue_icon" class="">info</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row container personal_information">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                        <form class="form row" action="{{ route('userPanel.update', $user->id) }}" method="POST" id="registrationForm"
                              style="margin-bottom: 0px;padding-right: 0.75rem;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;">
                            @csrf
                            @method('PATCH')
                            <div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label for="first_name">
                                            <p>name:</p>
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-info" name="first_name" id="first_name"
                                               value="{{ $user->name }}" placeholder=""
                                               title="enter your first name if any.">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label for="mobile">
                                            <p>phone:</p>
                                        </label>
                                        <input dir="ltr" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-info"
                                               value="{{ $user->phone }}"
                                               placeholder="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label for="email">
                                            <p>email:</p>
                                        </label>
                                        <input dir="ltr" type="email" class="form-info" name="email" id="email"
                                               value="{{ $user->email }}" placeholder="you@email.com"
                                               title="enter your email.">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <button class="btn btn-submit " type="submit">edit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'UserPanel')

@section('content')

    <div class="Profile" dir="rtl">
        <div class="row container">

            <aside class="sidebarWrap sidebar-group col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 ">
                @include('userPanel.sidebar')
            </aside>

            <div id="main" class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
                <div class="personal_information">
                    <p class="bold" id="blue_icon" class="">info</p>
                </div>
                @include('admin.layouts.adminErrors')
                <div class="row container personal_information">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                                <form class="form row"
                                    action="{{ route('userPanel.update', ['userPanel' => $user->id]) }}" method="POST"
                                    id="registrationForm"
                                    style="margin-bottom: 0px;padding-right: 0.75rem;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('PATCH')
                                    <div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <label for="first_name">
                                                    <p>name</p>
                                                </label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-info" name="name" id="first_name"
                                                    value="{{ $user->name }}" placeholder=""
                                                    title="enter your first name if any.">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <label for="mobile">
                                                    <p>phone</p>
                                                </label>
                                                <input dir="ltr" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-info"
                                                    value="{{ $user->phone }}" placeholder="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <label for="email">
                                                    <p>email</p>
                                                </label>
                                                <input dir="ltr" type="email" class="form-info" name="email" id="email"
                                                    value="{{ $user->email }}" placeholder="you@email.com"
                                                    title="enter your email.">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="btn btn-submit " type="submit">edit</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

@endsection
```

web.php

```
Route::namespace('Profile')->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function () {
        Route::resource('userPanel', 'userInfoController', ['only' => ['index', 'update']]);;
});
```

userInfoController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Profile;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class userInfoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        return view('userPanel.index', compact('user'));
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, User $userPanel)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:25'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'min:11', 'max:40', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($userPanel->id)],
            'phone' => ['numeric', 'min:11','regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($userPanel->id)],
        ]);
        $userPanel->update($data);

        return redirect(route('userPanel.index'));
    }
}
```